# golang equivalent to list of dicts to store data

Tags: go

I'm learning golang. I am trying to store a little bit of data, which I will then send to file.

What would be the golang equivalent of this python block? (a list of dicts)

```
friends = [
  {
    "name":"James",
    "age":44,
  },
  {
    "name":"Jane",
    "age":47,
  },
]
```

Would it be better to use a slice of maps or a struct?

I want to be able to filter the data (for example all friends over 45) and sort the data (lets imagine I've got 12+ records). then print it to the screen.

Comment: The direct comparison would be a slice of maps, but without an actual problem we can't say which is better.

Answer (score 3):

Many use cases where you use a dict in python, you want a struct for in Go, to get static typing. In your case this looks like a slice of structs to me:

```
type Friend struct{
  Name string `json:"name"`
  Age  int    `json:"age"`
}
```

and then you can serialize/deserialize to `[]*Person`

Answer (score 2):

Puuhon’s equivalent of `list` is a `slice`, both has same semantics and use cases.

But what to put into a slice? It depends of your dicts. If they are the same fields I recommend using `struct`s. Give it fields like above. Sometimes you have to store different keys and different string values for example. Define it as a map string to string:

```
map[string]string
```

As a last resort there’s a possibility to make dynamically typed map. But it’s not to overuse it because you lose all the benefits of static typing. Program becomes more error-prone and slower.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a little sample program that does what you want:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

type friend struct {
    name string
    age  int
}

func main() {
    friends := []friend{
        {"James", 44},
        {"Jane", 47},
        {"Bob", 30},
        {"Cesar", 90},
        {"John", 45},
    }

    over45 := filterFriends(friends, func(f friend) bool {
        return f.age > 45
    })
    fmt.Println("over 45:", over45)

    // note that sort.Sort will change the contents of the slice; if you want
    // to keep the original order as well, you would first have to copy that
    // slice and sort the copy
    sort.Sort(byAge(friends))
    fmt.Println("sorted by age:", friends)
}

// filterFriends takes your slice and a predicate to filter by, then returns a
// newly allocated list of friends that made it through the filter.
func filterFriends(friends []friend, pred func(friend) bool) []friend {
    var fit []friend
    for _, f := range friends {
        if pred(f) {
            fit = append(fit, f)
        }
    }
    return fit
}

// byAge implements the sort.Interface so we can pass it to sort.Sort.
type byAge []friend

func (f byAge) Len() int           { return len(f) }
func (f byAge) Less(i, j int) bool { return f[i].age < f[j].age }
func (f byAge) Swap(i, j int)      { f[i], f[j] = f[j], f[i] }
```

the output of the program is:

```
over 45: [{Jane 47} {Cesar 90}]
sorted by age: [{Bob 30} {James 44} {John 45} {Jane 47} {Cesar 90}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that your sample data seems to be homogeneous (friends share their properties), you can use a `slice` of `struct`s, as so:

```
type Friend struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

var friends []Friend = make([]Friend, 0)
```

now let's say you already added friends to that slice, you can filter those with `Age` greater than some number:

```
func filterFriendsAboveAge(allFriends []Friend, minAge int) []Friend {
    results := make([]Friend, 0) 
    for _, friend := range allFriends {
        if friend.Age > minAge {
            results = append(results, friend)
        }
    }
    return results
}
```

Please note that by calling this function, the Friend values in the returned slice will be copies of the original. If you need to preserve identity, use pointers instead.